# RecyclerView Loading Data Delay for Passing Json Data On ArrayList to New Activity

Tags: java, android, json

I am using Button to pass JSON data with ArrayList to another Activity on RecyclerView But When I run My App at first RecyclerView display empty lists and after presssing back button and clicking that button again RecyclerView show my list I don't know What's Wrong with my code Please Help me

```
    mainList = gson.fromJson(getIntent().getStringExtra("key"), new         TypeToken<List<MyData>>(){}.getType());

   if (mainList != null) {

       setrecyclerview(mainList);

   } else {
      pr.show();
   }
```

I'll try to use this but Don't Work:(

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private List<MyData> data_list;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
String get_info_url = "http://192.168.170.2/iVolleyPractice/user_info_check.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.data_recycler);
    data_list = new ArrayList<>();
    //load_from_data();



}

public void GoOnClick(View view) {

    load_from_data();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = new Gson().toJson(data_list);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
    intent.putExtra("key", json);
    startActivity(intent);



}

private void load_from_data() {

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, get_info_url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {

                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("users");

                for (int i = 0 ; i < jsonArray.length() ; i++)
                {
                    JSONObject users = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    MyData myData = new MyData();

                    myData.setName(users.getString("name"));
                    myData.setPassword(users.getString("password"));

                    data_list.add(myData);

                }



            } catch (Exception e) {}



        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    //setrecyclerview(data_list);
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

}
```

**MAinActivity 2**

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

public RecyclerView recyclerView;
public List<MyData> mainList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.go_recycle);
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    ProgressDialog pr = new ProgressDialog(this);
    this.getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArrayList("key");


    ProgressDialog pr = new ProgressDialog(this);
    this.getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArrayList("key");
    mainList = gson.fromJson(getIntent().getStringExtra("key"), new TypeToken<List<MyData>>(){}.getType());
    setrecyclerview(mainList);


}


private boolean setrecyclerview(List<MyData> data_list) {

    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, data_list);
    DividerItemDecoration divider = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), new LinearLayoutManager(this).getOrientation());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(divider);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return true;
}
```

}

**Adapter**

```
class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<MyData> myData;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<MyData> myData) {
    this.context = context;
    this.myData = myData;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int i) {

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_inflater, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(itemView);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.name.setText(myData.get(position).getName());
    holder.pass.setText(myData.get(position).getPassword());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return myData.size();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView name,pass;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_txt);
        pass = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pass_txt);
    }
}
```

**MyData**

```
 public class MyData implements Parcelable {

private String name,password;

public MyData() {
    this.name = name;
    this.password = password;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

protected MyData(Parcel in) {
    name = in.readString();
    password = in.readString();
}

public static final Creator<MyData> CREATOR = new Creator<MyData>() {
    @Override
    public MyData createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new MyData(in);
    }

    @Override
    public MyData[] newArray(int size) {
        return new MyData[size];
    }
};



@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(name);
    dest.writeString(password);
}
```

I wan when Click my button in MainActivity Display MyData In RecyclerView In MainActivity2 but For First run of my App Showing empty Recycler but when use back press button and click pass data button again display data

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity2, at first time when you call setrecyclerview() mainList is empty.

change your mainActivity2 code as below:

```
  public RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public List<MyData> mainList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.go_recycle);
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        ProgressDialog pr = new ProgressDialog(this);
        this.getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArrayList("key");


        mainList = gson.fromJson(getIntent().getStringExtra("key"), new TypeToken<List<MyData>>(){}.getType());
       if (!setrecyclerview(mainList) ) {
         //I don't know why you are doing this.because setrecyclerview() always returns true
           pr.show();
       } else {
           setrecyclerview(mainList);
       }


    }


    private boolean setrecyclerview(List<MyData> data_list) {

        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, data_list);
        DividerItemDecoration divider = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), new LinearLayoutManager(this).getOrientation());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(divider);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this...

```
if (!setrecyclerview(mainList) ) {
       pr.show();
   } else {
       mainList = gson.fromJson(getIntent().getStringExtra("key"), new TypeToken<List<MyData>>(){}.getType());
       setrecyclerview(mainList);
   }
```

with...

```
mainList = gson.fromJson(getIntent().getStringExtra("key"), new TypeToken<List<MyData>>(){}.getType());
       setrecyclerview(mainList);
```